# Search for methods/properties of an inherited class used by inheritor

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I'm tasked with rewriting some old code that we have, and I'm currently in the process of analyzing it. At first glance I believe that one of the classes is needlessly inheriting another class, because it seems to overwrite nearly every method and it doesn't seem to use any of the properties from the base class (again, just at first glance). Each class is ~1000 lines, so I was wondering if there's any features in VS-2013, Resharper, or any other tools that I can use to find the methods and properties of a class that are used by an inheritor without them being overridden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base class delete all `virtual` keywords
In inherited class change all `override` methods to `new` (hide the base class methods)

And than use `Find all references` on a base class

That will probably work